# 'Flot' resizing error behavior when axis has label

Tags: javascript, resize, flot

I'm using flot to add a graph to my page. I want the graph to be resizable and to have label on y axis. Those 2 work fine separately but noe together.... When i have label on axis and try to resize the label gains more and more 'space'
[image: Before]

[image: after resizing]

my html:

```
<div id ="ResizableContainer" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:900px;height:600px;">
<div id="placeholderForGraph" class="graph-placeholder" ></div>
```

my js:

```
var options = {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true },
    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
    xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" },
    yaxis: {
        axisLabel: obj[0].Unit,
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
        axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif",
        axisLabelPadding: 15,

}

    };
$("#placeholderForGraph").text('');
    $("#ResizableContainer").show();
$("#placeholderForGraph").plot([data], options);
```

Comment: Since you are able to do this, have you solved your previous question?  Are you using a flot plugin to add axis labels?  You are using jquery-ui resizable plugin but how are you resizing the plot?  Are you using the flot resize plugin?  You need to include all relevant information in your question...  Lastly, I've attempted to recreate your problem (http://jsfiddle.net/LE8H7/) but it is working fine for me...

Comment: @Mark no i havent solve the other question, the other one is when i try to open the graph in new window, this is when i load in page. I'm using flot plugins, and yes i've added all scripts needed(jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js;excanvas.js;flot.js;flot.axislabels.js;jquery.flot.resize.js; etc)

Comment: If you still have the error after comparing your code to the code from Mark's fiddle (check the `resize` event), build a fiddle from your code which reproduces your error. Then we can look at it.

Comment: @Raidri I can't repro my bug in fiddler. I've droppet the labels to avoid the bug. But big thenks to you both for spending the time :)